# How can I update Java hashmap values by previous value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

This question is a bit more complex that the title states.

What I am trying to do is store a map of {Object:Item} for a game where the Object represents a cupboard and the Item represents the content of the cupboard (i.e the item inside).

Essentially what I need to do is update the values of the items in a clockwise (positive) rotation; though I do NOT want to modify the list in any way after it is created, only shift the positions of the values + 1.

I am currently doing almost all That I need, however, there are more Object's than Item's so I use null types to represent empty cupboards. However, when I run my code, the map is being modified (likely as it's in the for loop) and in turn, elements are being overwritten incorrectly which after A while may leave me with a list full of nulls (and empty cupboards)

What I have so far...

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> cupboardItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

private static Map<Integer, Integer> rewardPrices = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

private static final int[] objects = { 10783, 10785, 10787, 10789, 10791, 10793, 10795, 10797 };

private static final int[] rewards = { 6893, 6894, 6895, 6896, 6897 };

static {
    int reward = rewards[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (reward > rewards[rewards.length - 1])
            cupboardItems.put(objects[i], null);
        else
            cupboardItems.put(objects[i], reward);

        reward++;
    }
}

// updates the items in the cupboards in clockwise rotation.
            for (int i = 0; i < cupboardItems.size(); i++) {
                if (objects[i] == objects[objects.length - 2])
                    cupboardItems.put(objects[i], cupboardItems.get(objects[0]));
                else if (objects[i] == objects[objects.length - 1])
                    cupboardItems.put(objects[i], cupboardItems.get(objects[1]));
                else
                    cupboardItems.put(objects[i], cupboardItems.get(objects[i + 2]));
            }
```

So how may I modify my code to update so i get the following results..

```
======
k1:v1
k2:v2
k3:v3
k4:none
=======
k1:none
k2:v1
k3:v2
k4:v3
```

?

Answer (score 0):

HashMap doesn't guarantee ordering, therefore if you need ordering, use ArrayList or LinkedList.

If you want to stick with HashMap, you need to sort the HashMap based on the key before each rotation. You can sort easily since the keys are Integer objects. But this will affect the performace.

Comment: Why not just use LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Thanks bcorso. Yes that would do and it is more appropriate for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Ragavan has a good answer if you want to stick to your approach. However, you are doing a lot of work to just rotate the items. It would be much more efficient to just rotate the index (using modulus) and keep the arrays the same:

```
final static List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>(
    Arrays.asList(10783, 10785, 10787, 10789, 10791, 10793, 10795, 10797));

final static List<Integer> rewards = new ArrayList<Integer>(
    Arrays.asList(6893, 6894, 6895, 6896, 6897, -1, -1, -1));

public static int getReward(int obj, int rot){
    int rotIndex = (objects.indexOf(obj) - rot)%objects.size();

    //modulus in java can be negative
    rotIndex = rotIndex < 0 ? rotIndex+objects.size():rotIndex;

    return rewards.get(rotIndex);
}

public static void main(String... args){
    //This should give 6897, which is the reward for obj 10783 after 4 rotations
    System.out.println(getReward(10783,4));
}
```